# Why does variable = variable + 1 work?

Tags: ruby

This is a Ruby Monk exercise and I'm having trouble wrapping my head around a particular concept.

For example, `"soup bowl" = "soup bowl" + 1` wouldn't be valid, so why does `@dishes_needed[a] = (@dishes_needed[a] || 0) + 1` work in the code below?  Is it because they are variables and not objects?  If so, why doesn't code `a = (a||0)+1` work when I initially set `a = "Soup"`:

```
class Dish
end

class Soup < Dish
end
class IceCream < Dish
end
class ChineseGreenBeans < Dish
end

class DeliveryTray
  DISH_BOWL_MAPPING = { 
    Soup => "soup bowl",
    IceCream => "ice cream bowl",
    ChineseGreenBeans => "serving plate"
  }

  def initialize
    @dishes_needed = {}
  end

  def add(dish)
    a = DISH_BOWL_MAPPING[dish.class]
     @dishes_needed[a] = (@dishes_needed[a] || 0) + 1
  end

  def dishes_needed
      return "None." if @dishes_needed.empty?

      @dishes_needed.map { |dish, count| "#{count} #{dish}"}.join(", ")
  end
end  

d = DeliveryTray.new
d.add Soup.new; d.add Soup.new
d.add IceCream.new

puts d.dishes_needed # should be "2 soup bowl, 1 ice cream bowl"
```

Comment: RHS of equal sign evaluates to value and LHS evaluates to variable reference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's simplify the `@dishes_needed` part, so you can understand the core concepts.  `@dishes_needed` is a hash and `@dishes_needed[a] = (@dishes_needed[a] || 0) + 1` adds a key, value pair to the hash.

This is a more simple way of looking at the code.  Here is the DISH_BOWL_MAPPING hash:

```
  DISH_BOWL_MAPPING = { 
    Soup => "soup bowl",
    IceCream => "ice cream bowl",
    ChineseGreenBeans => "serving plate"
  }
```

Get a certain element from the `DISH_BOWL_MAPPING` hash:

```
>> DISH_BOWL_MAPPING[Soup]
=> "soup bowl"
```

`@dishes_needed` is an empty hash:

```
>> @dishes_needed = {}
=> {}
```

If `a = Soup`, then here is how the line of code in question operates:

```
>> a = Soup
=> Soup
>> @dishes_needed[a] = (@dishes_needed[a] || 0) + 1
=> 1
>> @dishes_needed
=> {Soup=>1}
```

Let's decompose the right hand side of the equation that is confusing:

```
>> (@dishes_needed[a] || 0) + 1
>> (@dishes_needed[Soup] || 0) + 1
# @dishes_needed[Soup] is nil because Soup hasn't been added to the hash yet
>> (nil || 0) + 1
# nil || 0 evaluates to 0 because nil and false are falsey in Ruby
>> (0) + 1
>> 1
```

Subsequent called to `@dishes_needed[Soup]` evaluate to 1 now that the hash has been updated:

```
>> @dishes_needed[Soup]
=> 1
```

This says that the key (Soup) equals the value plus one (in this case, the value isn't established yet, so it results in 1).

If `a = "Soup"` then `a = (a||0)+1` evaluates to `a = "Soup" + 1` and you cannot add an integer and string in Ruby.  If you convert 1 to a string, then the expression evaluates correctly.

```
a = (a||0)+1.to_s
```

Answer (score 2):

We can not divided things as variables and objects in ruby. Everything here is an Object.

about your code the only thing to understand is that + method(yeah its a method) will not work with the string objects as you are trying in both the cases. it works in that case because if the object was NILL you are initializing it with a Fixnum object 0 and + method works fine with Fixnum.

Hope I answered you. If more clarification needed please ask.

Answer (score 1):

In this code:

```
a = DISH_BOWL_MAPPING[dish.class]
@dishes_needed[a] = (@dishes_needed[a] || 0) + 1
```

`a` is either going to be a string from one of the values in the `DISH_BOWL_MAPPING` Hash or `nil` if the key isn't there.  If it's `nil`, then `@dishes_needed[a]` will also be nil, which makes `(@dishes_needed[a] || 0)` evaluate to `0`, which you then add `1` to.  The key concept here is that `Hash#[]` returns `nil` if the key isn't found (unless you've set the default to something else, which you haven't here).  Obviously the net effect here is that you increment `@dishes_needed[a]` if it already exists or set it to `1` if it doesn't yet exist.

Contrast that with:

```
a = "Soup"
a = (a||0)+1
```

Here, `a` always starts as `"Soup"`, so `(a||0)` is always `"Soup"`, which you can't add `1` to.